# update a elasticsearch query with python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I would like to update an elasticsearch query with python.

From a first query to a Db I get this example of query as a string which I transform in a
json file through:

```
query = json.loads(string_query)
```

example of the query:

```
{'bool': 
    {'must': [ 
            {'range': {'field': {'gte': lowerbound, 'lt': upperbound}}}
              ],
  'must_not': [{'match_phrase': {'field': {'query': 'word'}}}]}}
```

What I would like to do is to add fields to the query as:

```
{'bool': 
    {'must': [ 
            {'range': {'field': {'gte': lowerbound, 'lt': upperbound}}},
            {'range': {'field-2': {'gte': lowerbound, 'lt': upperbound}}}
            {'bool':  {'should': {'bool': {'must': 
                           [ 
                               {'range': {'field': {'gte': lowerbound, 'lt': upperbound}}},
                               {'range': {'field-2': {'gte': lowerbound, 'lt': upperbound}}}
                           ]}}}},
              ],
  'must_not': [{'match_phrase': {'field': {'query': 'word'}}}]}}
```

is it possible to exploit some libraries or it should be done by 'hand' by building 
a new json from the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a python question btw. Output of `json.loads` is a dictionary . You can modify the way you work with a python dictionary.

For example

```
query["bool"]["must"] += [ < your query> ]
```

You can pass this query object to requests.post() or library of your choice to submit request to ES . BTW - you may want to look at elastic client for python [elasticsearch-py](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py)

Comment: thanks for the answer, I am already using the elastic client and I was wandering if it was possible to build queries also through some libraries as in java with `org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders`

Comment: its slightly different model -> https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search_dsl.html#queries